# Break foreach() loop and store remaining entries in new array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop which compares a category field for the previous and current record in the array and checks that they match. if the two fields do not match the loop is broken.

```
    $rows = array();

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){            
            $rows[] = $row;
    }


    $previous = 'FROG';

    echo"<div class='rowtable'>";

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $commondraft = $row['Name'];
        $current = $row['Category'];

        if($current==$previous){

        echo"<a href='/stocklist/".$row['id']."/".commonName($commondraft)."' class='row'>";
        echo"<div class='common'>".$row['Name']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='descr'>".$row['Description']."</div>";
        echo"<div class='sex'>".$row['Sex']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='age'>".$row['Age']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='size'>".$row['Size']."</div>";  
        echo"<div class='origin'>".$row['Origin']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='scientific'>".$row['Scientific']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='prices'>".$row['Price']."</div>"; 

        echo"</a>";
        }

        $previous=$current;
        }
```

I need to find a way to store the remaining records in the array into a new array so that they can be used elsewhere in a second foreach loop.

SOLUTION:
Followed @LukasS, suggestion. Thought i'd post the code i am now using below for anyone else interested:

```
$query =    "SELECT * FROM livestock    WHERE Category = 'frog' OR Category = 'newt'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));  
    $rows = array();

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){            
            $rows[$row['Category']][] = $row;}



    $previous = 'FROG';

    echo"<div class='rowtable'>";

    foreach($rows['FROG'] as $row)
    {
        $commondraft = $row['Name'];
        $current = $row['Category'];

        if($current==$previous){

        echo"<a href='/stocklist/".$row['id']."/".commonName($commondraft)."' class='row'>";
        echo"<div class='common'>".$row['Name']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='descr'>".$row['Description']."</div>";
        echo"<div class='sex'>".$row['Sex']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='age'>".$row['Age']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='size'>".$row['Size']."</div>";  
        echo"<div class='origin'>".$row['Origin']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='scientific'>".$row['Scientific']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='prices'>".$row['Price']."</div>"; 

        echo"</a>";
        }

        $previous=$current;
        }



    echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should use associative arrays if there is a way of keeping keys clean.

So for example instead `$rows[]` separate them with `Category` key: `$rows[$row['Category']][] = $row;` and use for each on that associative array.

Comment: Thanks @LukasS, followed your idea in the end and it seems to be working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you could make the `if` depend on the comparison and boolean. then if it misses it switches the boolean on the else and uses that to dump the rest into a new array

```
$bool = TRUE;
$newArray = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
    if($current==$previous && $bool === TRUE){
        /*Things happening*/
    }else{
        $bool = FALSE;
        $newArray[] = $row;
    }
}
```